# Betweenness centrality and least average shortest path

Tags: graphs

TL;DR: How do I justify mathematically that vertices with the highest betweenness centrality do not necessarily have the smallest mean shortest path?

I am currently studying the London Underground as a hobby. Recently, I have been calculating some graph metrics for different vertices (ie. Tube stations) in the London Underground network. 
From my calculations, the top 5 stations for betweenness centrality are

```
Baker Street               0.344084
King's Cross St.Pancras    0.303868
Liverpool Street           0.267392
Green Park                 0.263264
Mile End                   0.229449
```

After that, I calculated the mean shortest path from each station to every other station and the top 5 stations (smallest mean shortest paths) were

```
Green Park       8.901887
Oxford Circus    9.007547
Bond Street      9.090566
Baker Street     9.211321
Westminster      9.339623
```

I was expecting the station with the highest betweenness centrality to have the smallest mean shortest path and the data proved me wrong.  I am looking for a more mathematically rigorous justification for why greatest betweenness does not imply least average shortest path. 
All ideas and hints are appreciated.

Comment: You have a counter example; that is mathematical proof of your claim/intuition. It's not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I wasn't very clear. I just produced a counterexample, but intuitively I was expecting the node with the largest betweenness to be the node with the least mean shortest path. Instead that's not the case. I'm struggling to understand why greatest betweenness does not guarantee least mean shortest path.

Comment: Try to find the simplest possible counterexample, and then you can try to see where your intuition goes wrong.